Check if a point lies within a rectangle by using the matrix form of $Ax \leq b$
I am working on a personal gaming project, and I am applying some linear algebraic concepts to it. For this concept, I want to determine if a point lies within $4$ points forming a rectangle by using the form $Ax \leq b$, where $A$ is a matrix, $x$ is the random point, and $b$ is a vector.
Below, I am showing you two examples where the random point is indicated as red, and the rectangle should be given by $4$ points. In this case, the points are like so $(1,3)$, $(4,6)$, $(6,4)$, $(3,1)$. The rule is that each edge is represented by the sequence of the points.
Unfortunately, my reputation is below 10, so I am unable to post any images for better clarification. Basically, if you draw the coordinates, you will see that it forms a rectangle. Take a random point, $\text{P}$, and the expression $Ax \leq b$ should return true if it falls within the rectangle boundaries. False otherwise.
I know how to do this using code, but I want to do it on paper by simply providing the matrix $A$ and the vector $b$, and if it satisfies the condition, then the point is inside the rectangle. If not, then it falls outside.
By doing it using a matrix $A$ and vector $b$, it simply reduces the calculation instead of using a Ray-casting algorithm, as in my project, there will be thousands of rectangles, meaning that will be less computationally expensive by using the form of $Ax \leq b$.
Any help will be very appreciated!

Thank you for the edit, @Bml.

You're welcome!

Are you looking for a way to calculate $A$ and $b$ given a set of four coordinate points?

It's just a smidge more complicated (you need two inequalities). Here is how one derives these:

Let the rectangle be described by $P_i=(x_i,y_i)$, with $i=\overline{1,4}$. For simplicity, we can calculate the width and the height of this rectangle as
$$w=\sqrt{(x_4-x_1)^2+(y_4-y_1)^2}\\h=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$$
The position of the point we want to test is $P=(x,y)$. The position of point $P$ with respect to $P_1$ is $P-P_1=(x-x_1, y-y_1)$
Calculate the $P-P_1$ vector in a coordinate frame along the rectangle width and height using dot product:$$(P-P_1)_w=\frac1w(P_4-P_1)\cdot(P-P_1)\\(P-P_1)_h=\frac1h(P_2-P_1)\cdot(P-P_1)$$
In order that the point to be inside the rectangle you need to have $$0\le(P-P_1)_w\le w\\0\le(P-P_1)_h\le h$$
You can write these numbers using a matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}\le\begin{pmatrix}\frac{x_4-x_1}w & \frac{y_4-y_1}w\\\frac{x_2-x_1}h & \frac{y_2-y_1}h\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x-x_1\\y-y_1\end{pmatrix}\le \begin{pmatrix}w\\h\end{pmatrix}$$
The $A$ matrix is then $$A=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{x_4-x_1}w & \frac{y_4-y_1}w\\\frac{x_2-x_1}h & \frac{y_2-y_1}h\end{pmatrix}$$
You can then write $$A\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\y_1\end{pmatrix}\le A\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\le A\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\y_1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}w\\h\end{pmatrix}$$
For the vectors, $\le$ means each of the elements.

